# Compare two versions of text

Tags: windows, text-editors

Sometimes I need to compare two versions of short text, and looking for the most efficient way to do it

- I know I could save them to Word documents and compare them, that's the baseline, I'd like to find something easier / quicker
- I know there are several online tools doing it for free, however my texts are often confidentials
- I've access to Office tools and Notepad++
- I've found a question here doing the same in Vim, however I'd like to avoid having another tool just for this purpose

Comment: Software recommendations are out of scope here at Super User. I am 90% that Notepad++ supports comparing the contents of two files.

Comment: @Ramhound Not plain Notepad++, only with compare plugin installed. If you want to avid third party programs there is still `fc.exe` on the command line which can compare files. If you decide to use a third party program I would recommend kdiff3 for Windows (open source).

Comment: Asking what's the *most efficient* or *quicker way* to do something is a matter of opinion and not a good fit for questions on SuperUser.

Comment: @Ramhound I've a problem which is on topic here and want to solve it. Solution isn't necessarily software recommendation, feel free to improve the question to fit better

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: I've a workaround, but I'm looking for a more efficient solution, I don't think that would be too subjective. I'm not native English, feel free to edit my question to make a better fit.

Comment: Your English is actually quite good IMHO. At any rate, a better way to ask this question is to describe your current process and tell us where you're running into trouble. Then let answerers take it upon themselves to say how to address those specific problems.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Notepad++**

1. Open Notepad++
2. Click on the ‘Plugins’ menu at the top of the screen
3. Click on ‘Plugin Manager’ then ‘Show Plugin Manager’
4. A list of available plugins will appear – if it does not you need to check your 5. Internet connection. If you are behind a proxy server you will need to enter the details in the ‘Settings’ section (button at the bottom left of window).
   [image]
5. Scroll down until you see ‘Compare’
6. Place a tick next to the name then click on the ‘Install’ button. Once the plugin is installed you will be prompted to restart Notepad++
   [image]
7. Click ‘Yes’ to finish the install.
8. Now that the plugin has been installed, open two files
9. Click on the ‘Plugins’ menu then ‘Compare’ and ‘Compare’ again
   The files will be displayed, side by side, with the differences highlighted
   [image]